# Picasso error when trying to fetch with jsoup in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup, picasso

So I'm trying to fetch data from the website, images and title and I'm loading in recylerview with Picasso library but when the app launches it stops working and I get the error.

The main code that fetches

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.example.com";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("span.thumbnail");

            int size = data.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                String imgUrl = data.select("span.thumbnail")
                        .select("img")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("src");
                String title = data.select("h4.titles")
                        .select("span")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();
                parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title));
                Log.d("items", "img: " + imgUrl + " .title: " + title);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also call the library with

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
```

And upon running the app I get the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.event_finder, PID: 8531
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
    at com.example.event_finder.ParseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ParseAdapter.java:38)
    at com.example.event_finder.ParseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ParseAdapter.java:17)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1849)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Edit:

**at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)**

```
public RequestCreator load(@Nullable String path) {
    if (path == null) {
      return new RequestCreator(this, null, 0);
    }
    if (path.trim().length() == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path must not be empty.");  **this line**
    }
    return load(Uri.parse(path));
  }
```

**at com.example.event_finder.ParseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ParseAdapter.java:38)**

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ParseItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(parseItem.getTitle());
    Picasso.get().load(parseItem.getImgUrl()).into(holder.imageView);   **this line**
}
```

**at com.example.event_finder.ParseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ParseAdapter.java:17)**

`public class ParseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParseAdapter.ViewHolder>` {

Answer (score 0):

`parseItem.getImgUrl()` << this method is returning an empty string. See
`ParseAdapter.java:38`

follow how this gets produced (backwards) and we can see `ParseItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);` (`ParseAdapter.java:36`) recieves `position` as an index (coming from the method arguments passed in). That index is referencing an empty string in a list.

Since you're adding new `ParseItem`s as part of your JSoup code to what I'm assuming is a list(?), it seems

`imgUrl` in:

```java
            String url = "https://www.example.com";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("span.thumbnail");

            int size = data.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                String imgUrl = data.select("span.thumbnail")
                        .select("img")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("src");
```

is returning an empty `String` (`""`) and you're populating that in the list of `ParseItem`s

Comment: I have updated the answer please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: think I've worked it backwards far enough now that the answer should make sense to you

Comment: Yeah... I thought `http://example.com` was just a **'filler address'** cuz he didn't want to include the real one... There's obviously no image on that page :)

Comment: I have done some changes and now it doesn't crash anymore but it does not show anything, here I uploaded the entire file https://github.com/iusedtodo420/event_finder

Comment: @Y2020-09 is right - www.example.com is (on purpose) kept as an unregistered domain so it can be used for example code. You need to use a real URL